# Increase unix time

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I have a unix time eg: var later= 135000;

When I take the variable later -= 1000 I am able to get 134000.

But when I take the variable later += 1000 I get 1350001000.

How can I increase my unix time?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var later = "<?php echo $unix_time; ?>";
   var stop= setInterval('countdown()',1000);

   function countdown(plus_ten) {
        var now = new Date();

        var now_time= now.getTime()/1000;
        now_time= Math.floor(now_time);

        if(plus_ten){
            later = later + 1000;
            alert(later);
        }

        var sec = later- now_time;
        if(sec<=0){
            clearInterval(stop);
            alert('hello');
        }

        sec= Math.floor(sec);
        var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
        var hour = Math.floor(min / 60);

        hour %= 24;
        min %= 60;
        sec %= 60;

        document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hour;
        document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = min;
        document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = sec;       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Also, i suggest you do `var stop= setInterval(countdown,1000);` instead of `var stop= setInterval('countdown()',1000);` as the former is the recommended, more efficient.

Comment: @Jian - don't forget to "Accept" the best answer by clicking on the checkmark.  It's an important part of StackOverflow participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable 'later' is assigned a string value when you do:

```
var later = "<?php echo $unix_time; ?>";
```

You should instead do:

```
var later = <?php echo $unix_time; ?>; // i.e. no quotes around the time stamp
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Hey thanks so much. I put the quotes around it initially becos after I put it my timer runs, if not it did not run. But now it runs without the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that JavaScript is a loosely typed language.  Whether your variable gets handled as a integer or a string depends on the context in which you use it.

The `-` (minus) operator is obviously arithmetic, so JS knows to subtract.  But the `+` operator is also used to concatenate strings, so if you want JS to do addition, you may need to be more explicit.  You've put the contents of `later` inside double quotes, which hints to JS that you want it to be treated as a string.  So:

```
var later = parseInt("<?php echo $unix_time; ?>");
```

or

```
later = later - 0 + 1000;  /* hints at arithmetic, then adds 1000 */
```

Quotes are a Good Thing, in case `$unix_time` contains something unexpected.